# how should i fixed problem with " ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer expected shape=(None, 25, 1)"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

```
# Initialising the RNN
regressor = Sequential()

# Adding the first LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 64, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1),activation="sigmoid"))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding a second LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 64, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding a third LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 64, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
# Adding a fourth LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 64))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Adding the output layer
regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))

# Compiling the RNN
regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

# Fitting the RNN to the Training set
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 200, batch_size = 5)
```

```
timestep = 45
def insert_end(Xin,new_input):
    for i in range(timestep-1):
        Xin[:,i,:] = Xin[:,i+1,:]
    Xin[:,timestep-1,:] = new_input
    return Xin

future = 100
forcast = []
Xin = X_test[-1:]
for i in range(future):
    out = regressor.predict(Xin, batch_size=1)    
    forcast.append(out[0,0]) 
    Xin = insert_end(Xin,out[0,0])
```

**I wanna predict the forecasting value for the future but i got the error like "ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 25, 1), found shape=(None, 5, 1)",what should i do?**

Comment: what is X_train shape and Xin shape ?

Comment: The `input_shape` defined in the model definition and the provided in the model training part (model.fit) is different. Could you please help us to know the shape of X_train?